# How to add environmental vector arrows to NMDS in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I'm trying to make an NMDS plot to show the relationship between rockpool species presence/absence and different environmental variables. I'm not sure how to show all my data here so if you need more info let me know and tell me how to share it! I've attached screenshots to show part of my data so you can get the jist of how it's laid out. In the first image, row names are species and columns have 1s for presence and 0s for absence.

I've also included my R script so far. At the moment I have shapes representing rock pool substrate (circles for bedrock and triangles for cobble) and I have shape colours representing level of wave exposure. I want to represent the other environmental variables (Direction, Depth and Volume) as vector arrows if possible. Any help on how to do this would be really appreciated!

Data images: https://postimg.cc/gallery/Dw2fCCV

```
> setwd("H:/DataR")
> nmdsdata = read.csv("nmdsdatav2.csv")
> library(vegan)
> library(ggplot2)

> data_1 <- nmdsdata[,24:73]    
> data_env <- nmdsdata[,2:6]
> data_env$Substrate <- as.factor(data_env$Substrate)
> data_env$Exposure <- as.factor(data_env$Exposure)
> data_env$Direction <- as.factor(data_env$Direction)
> data_env$Depth_cm <- as.factor(data_env$Depth_cm)
> data_env$Volume_L <- as.factor(data_env$Volume_L)

> nmds <- metaMDS(data_1, distance = "jaccard", k = 2)

> data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds)) 
> data.scores <- cbind(data.scores, Substrate = nmdsdata$Substrate)
> data.scores <- cbind(data.scores, Exposure = nmdsdata$Exposure)
> data.scores <- cbind(data.scores, Depth = nmdsdata$Depth_cm)
> data.scores <- cbind(data.scores, Volume = nmdsdata$Volume_L)
> data.scores <- cbind(data.scores, Direction = nmdsdata$Direction)

> species.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds, "species"))
> species.scores$species <- rownames(species.scores)

> head(species.scores)

> nmds.plot <- ggplot(data.scores, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2))+
  geom_point(aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, colour = factor(data_env$Exposure), shape = factor(data_env$Substrate)), size = 4)+
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 1, linetype = "solid"))+
  labs(colour = "Exposure", shape = "Substrate")+
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.text = element_text(size = 12), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 10))+ 
  geom_text(data=species.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=species), alpha=0.5, size = 3.5)

> nmds.plot
```

Comment: Please use `dput(nmdsdata)` to include your data, or use one of the built in data sets (e.g. dune & dune.env). You can use `vegan::envfit` to fit the arrows. Look at `ggvegan` for an autoplot for envfit objects. ggvegan is on github

Answer (score 0):

Check `envfit()` function in vegan documentation. Based in your code, you may try:

```
>plot(nmds)    
>envfit(nmds, data_env, add=TRUE)
```

Also check the summary of the envfit()

edit: I see you're trying to plot using ggplot2, however `envfit()` only work with base plots